# Rails 4 ajax saving but not reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

My AJAX is working with the comments, but not with my posts, so I know js and jquery are loaded, plus I checked in the console.

The part where I removeclass in the js also doesn't execute(javascript):

```
$(".statusform").on("ajax:beforeSend", function(evt, xhr, settings) {
  return $(this).find('textarea').addClass('uneditable-input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}).on("ajax:success", function(evt, data, status, xhr) {
 $(this).find('textarea').removeClass('uneditable-input').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled').val('');
  return $(xhr.responseText).hide().insertAfter($('#after')).show('slow');
                                                  });
```

In my controller:

```
respond_to do |format|  
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to posts_path, :notice => '<i class="fa fa-check fa-5x"></i>'.html_safe }
       # format.js   # @current_item = @post 
        #format.json { render action: 'index', status: :created, location: @post }
        format.js {render :partial => "posts/postline", :locals => { :post => @post }, :layout => false, :status => :created }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
```

the view:

```
<%= render :partial => 'posts/postline', :collection => @posts, :as => :post %>
```

everything renders but when I hit submit, I have to refresh the page manually to see the post in index.

How can I append the new post? I'm trying in my js above but not sure what isn't working or what I'm missing.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the javascript console? Also - you say it works for comments - how does you post-javascript differ from your comment-javascript?

Comment: javascript code in my comments is the same, but comments is seperate from this question, comments is a separate controller

Comment: Yes I know that. but if they're doing the same thing... then it often helps to see what the differences are between the code to see why this code is failing when that code works.

Comment: so you don't see anything in the code I've provided?

Comment: i don't want to desk-check every line of your code if you have an error that will quickly point me in the right direction ;)

Comment: I recommend that you: 1) open the javascript console. 2) go through your ajax-call by hand yourself and find at what point it fails. (eg try seeing if this returns something: `$(this).find('textarea')` then try `$(this).find('textarea').addClass('uneditable-input')` etc etc. see what fails and what works to rule out the bits that work and narrow down your search.

Comment: the ajax saves the post, it just doesn't refresh/append the content

Comment: Right - which is why I suggested that you manually try the refreshing javascript in the javascript console... to see what part it's choking on. :)

Comment: @FranklinDeLosSantos why aren't you following rails flow of ajax? In rails we write ajax success inside js.erb files

Comment: yes I know, I just wanna get something working, I'll rearrange things later, better have something working than nothing, just hacking it together right now